# Formatting digits in attribute of table MySQL

Tags: mysql

So I've got a table with an entry called ShippingPerPound that should be able to store digits in the format ##.##.

I have no idea how to set that as a default and there doesn't seem to be a readily available answer in the MySQL documentation.

Comment: There are a variety of data types which can be used to store decimal data: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/numeric-types.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use decimal datatype to do it

```
CREATE TABLE `num` (
  `id` int(4) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `d` decimal(4,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

MariaDB [test]> select * from num;
+------+--------+
| id   | d      |
+------+--------+
| 0001 |  12.34 |
| 0002 |  12.00 |
| 0003 |   1.00 |
| 0004 |  24.50 |
| 0005 | -13.90 |
+------+--------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [test]>
```